# Universal way to Run command line programs and process input on Non-English Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, command-line, multilingual

I'm working on a tool with GUI that allows users to easily run Command line tools/programs, basically, my program runs those tool as a process, parses console output and summarizes it for the user on the UI. Most of the commands are windows built-in e.g. net start, windows update etc

This works fine on English version of Windows, however, the problem are Non-English Single-Language versions of windows that might only have Italian etc. On these systems, all windows built-in programs/tools output in the system's language (e.g. Italian). Is there a universal way to process console output that is language independent or force output in English/ASCII even if only one non-English language is available on the system?

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe have a look first, what kind of language is available by the system and if it's not English, then try to set it via [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) class. [CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) property to get system's culture.
Untested, but maybe it will work. Required is, that on non-english machines English language is available - if not. There will be no way to accomplish this. Sorry.